# 2 MouseListener in 2 different class Java

Tags: java, mouseevent, actionlistener, mouselistener, mouse-listeners

I have a problem with MouseListeners, in fact i have two java class, the first is a Menu with buttons, each button call a method with MouseListeners and a second one as a map, in the second class i have a method which use a MouseListener to locate a clic on the map, the problem is that this MouseListener doesn't work because of the listener in the first class button.
here is my code to have a clear idea : 
First class (The Menu with buttons) :

```
button4.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() { 
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) { 
        //button4.removeMouseListener (button4.getMouseListeners()[0]);
        //System.out.println("Mouse Free");
        map.locateClick() ;

    } 
});
```

Second Class : (The map)

```
// Mouse Listener
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) { } ;
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) { } ;
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { } ;
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) { } ;

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
this.ClickIsHere = true ;
this.XClick = e.getX() ;
this.YClick = e.getY() ;

synchronized (lock) {
    lock.notify() ;
}­­­­­­
```

Comment: `"the problem is that this MouseListener dosnt work because of the listener in the first class button."` -- I doubt that this is the reason for the 2nd MouseListener not to work. consider creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where you condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles and runs, has no outside dependencies (such as need to link to a database or images), has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem. Note also that JButtons should use ActionListeners.

Comment: Yes, in fact i had a Launcher class with a command line, and the application work fine, but im trying to add a Swing user interface.
There is no way to call a methode with listener with a button listener ?